# Identify columns in a table that are referenced or used on other tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm seeking assistance in crafting a SQL query to determine which columns in a table ('Books') are either referenced in or used by other tables. Table ('Books') has 5 fields, which are: id, author_id, genre_id, title, and page. I aim to obtain a result similar to the following:

| field_name | used_on | referenced_from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | transaction_details | null |
| id | revision_details | null |
| author_id | null | authors |
| genre_id | null | genres |
| title | null | null |
| page | null | null |

Let me explain each result from the query I expected to do:

- For the 'id' field, the column is used in the 'transaction_details' table because this table contains transaction details related to a book's ID.
- For the 'author_id' field, the column is not used in any other table, but it originates from the 'authors' table, where author information is stored.
- Similarly, for the 'genre_id' field, it is not used in any other table but is derived from the 'genres' table, which contains genre information.
- For the 'title' and 'page' fields, both results should be null because these columns are standalone pieces of information about the books.

Here is my current attempt at the SQL query:

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @TABLENAME = 'books'   

SELECT 
    c.name AS field_name,
    CASE WHEN used_on_table.name = @TABLENAME THEN NULL ELSE used_on_table.name END AS used_on,
    CASE WHEN referenced_from_table.name = @TABLENAME THEN NULL ELSE referenced_from_table.name END AS referenced_from
FROM 
    sys.columns c
LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
LEFT JOIN sys.tables used_on_table ON c.object_id = used_on_table.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.tables referenced_from_table ON fkc.referenced_object_id = referenced_from_table.object_id
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = @TABLENAME;
```

However, the results are not as expected, and I've learned that:

1. There's one result on that SQL that has the same outside table
2. There are instances where the same table appears in both 'used_on' and 'referenced_from,' which is incorrect.
3. The result includes the table itself ('books') in 'used_on' and 'referenced_from,' which is not intended.
4. 'used_on' and 'referenced_from' should never be the same table for a given field.
5. Ideally, 'used_on' and 'referenced_from' should be either null or refer to different tables.
6. On a big database that has a lot of tables, keep in mind that some field might have multiple 'used_on'.

My result from SQL is still wrong:

| field_name | used_on | referenced_from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | null | null |
| author_id | authors | authors |
| genre_id | genres | genres |
| title | null | null |
| page | null | null |

Additionally, I add table definition along with its data:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE genres (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE books (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    author_id INT,
    genre_id INT,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    page INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id)
);

CREATE TABLE transaction_details (
    transaction_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    book_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(id)
);

CREATE TABLE revision_details (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    book_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(id)
);


INSERT INTO authors VALUES (101);
INSERT INTO genres VALUES (201);
INSERT INTO books VALUES (1, 101, 201, 'Book Title 1', 150);
INSERT INTO transaction_details VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO revision_details VALUES (1, 1);
```

Comment: Tables in databases have columns, not fields.

Comment: `used_on_table ` and `referenced_from_table ` join conditions are identical (`fkc.referenced_object_id`) - a clear mistake. This is why you are getting "duplicate" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your query is only half the solution. You are getting all the columns in your table which reference another table. But you need a another join to `[sys].[foreign_key_columns]` to get the tables and columns which reference your table.

```
SELECT 
  c.[name] column_name
  , fk_tab.[name] used_on
  , rft.[name] referenced_from
FROM [sys].[columns] c
-- Tables which we reference
LEFT JOIN [sys].[foreign_key_columns] fkc
  ON fkc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
  AND fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
LEFT JOIN [sys].[tables] rft
  ON fkc.referenced_object_id = rft.[object_id]
-- Tables which reference us
LEFT JOIN [sys].[foreign_key_columns] fkcr
  ON fkcr.referenced_object_id = c.[object_id]
  AND fkcr.referenced_column_id = c.column_id
LEFT JOIN sys.tables fk_tab
   ON fk_tab.[object_id] = fkcr.parent_object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.[object_id]) = @TABLENAME
ORDER BY c.[name];
```

Returns as requested:

| field_name | used_on | referenced_from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| author_id | null | authors |
| genre_id | null | genres |
| id | transaction_details | null |
| id | revision_details | null |
| page | null | null |
| title | null | null |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sOjXBLNK)

Comment: Sincere thanks for helping me Mr., I'd really appreciate it.